# Entity Framework MySql Insert creating tmp table?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-6.1

I am using EF 6.1 CodeFirst via the ASP.Net Identity 2.0 framework.  I extended the `DBContext` to contain a new table, for storing invites to my application:

```
public class MySqlDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    <snip/>

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the database set for user invites.
    /// </summary>
    public IDbSet<ApplicationInvite> Invites { get; set; }

    <snip/>
}
```

And utilized the migration framework to create a migration to add the `Invites` table.

Here is the code I am using to insert:

```
public class InviteStore : IInviteStore
{
    private readonly MySqlDbContext mySqlDbContext;
    private readonly IDbSet<ApplicationInvite> invites;

    public InviteStore(MySqlDbContext mySqlDbContext)
    {
        this.mySqlDbContext = mySqlDbContext;
        this.invites = this.mySqlDbContext.Set<ApplicationInvite>();
    }

    public async Task<bool> CreateAsync(ApplicationInvite invite)
    {
        this.invites.Add(invite);
        await this.mySqlDbContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return true;
    }
}
```

What I am seeing now is an exception thrown when attempting to insert into the `Invites` table.  I can't understand where the `Table 'MyDatabase.tmpIdentity_Invites' doesn't exist` is coming from.

```
{
  "exceptionMessage": "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.",
  "exceptionType": "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException",
  "innerException": {
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.",
    "exceptionType": "System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException",
    "stackTrace": "   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.<UpdateAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.
    <ExecuteInTransactionAsync>d__3d`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.
        <SaveChangesToStoreAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.
            <SaveChangesInternalAsync>d__31.MoveNext()",
    "innerException": {
      "message": "An error has occurred.",
      "exceptionMessage": "Table 'MyDatabase.tmpIdentity_Invites' doesn't exist",
      "exceptionType": "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException",
      "stackTrace": "   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.
                <ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.
                    <UpdateAsync>d__0.MoveNext()"
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help, please?

Thanks.

**EDIT**
It looks like the root cause was that the migration did not complete successfully.  It was throwing:

```
You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)
```

I found the root cause to be that the MySQL user who instantiated the migration did not have 'Super' privileges on the database, and thus the migration wasn't complete entirely -- even though the row was added to the `__MigrationsHistory` table indicating so... After rolling back the migration, and adding 'Super' privileges, then re-doing the migration, it all worked fine.

Comment: When you check your MySQL server, does the table 'MyDatabase.tmpIdentity_Invites' show? Did "migrations" actually add it?

Comment: No, there is not a `MyDatabase.tmpIdentity_Invites` table.  As far as I could tell the 'migration' worked fine -- as the `Invites` table was created successfully and the row was added to the `__MigrationsHistory` table.  I found the root cause to be that the MySQL user who instantiated the migration did not have 'Super' privileges on the database, and thus the migration wasn't complete entirely -- even though the row was added...  After rolling back the migration, and adding 'Super' privileges, then re-doing the migration, it all worked fine.